# How to export angular charts to an image including legend

Tags: angularjs, html5-canvas, angular-chart

I am using this code for export angular charts as a image.

var canvas = document.getElementById(chartUnqId);

var content = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

scope.chartImageUrl = content;

this is working fine but it's not including legend in image.I need my legend and canvas save as a png.

Comment: legends are set in html; toDataURL() only gets the content of the canvas. You may try [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/)